# Angular15 MDC Components Input Style

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am currently in the process of updating Angular 14 applications to Angular 15, and I've encountered significant style changes in Angular Material (MDC Components). Is there a straightforward approach to preserving the previous layout, particularly for the Input components, without relying on custom CSS? Redesigning the entire application layout appears to be impractical, especially considering the height difference of the input components. This difference disrupts various visual elements.

Old default appearance:

[image]

New default appearance:

[image]

Comment: I answered your question, but I still don't fully understand why the changes of heights / margins / ... disrupt the layout of your application in such a big way.

Comment: Hi @GJojannes, Didnt you face any jasmine test cases failing issue after Angular15 upgrade? Also, can you please tell me how did you refer/came to know, what material 15 class needs to be updated/replaced with which MDC equivalent class? Is there any documentation/website to refer and compare to resolve the TODO(mdc-migration): comments left by MDC migration step? And to fix all the css issues?

Comment: Fixing all CSS issues was a nightmare. It was all done manually. I did not have any specific problems with jasmine tests.

Comment: Yes, its true that MDC is a nightmare for Angular devs. Could you please tell what approaches/documentations/references you have used while fixing all CSS issues?

Comment: Nothing specific. Just get the Code to run and look at all UIs and "reimplement" everything that does not look right. Unfortunately there is nothing else I could tell you.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the styles have been updated to align with the Material Design version 2 (M2) standard. For most of the components there are only minor notable changes.

This is not necessarily the case for the form field component. As per [migration guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration#form-field):

> The "legacy" and "standard" form-field appearance settings no longer exist, as these have been dropped from the Material Design spec.

Apparently, you have been using the "standard" form field style. With MDC, the new default form field style is "fill". This is why you are seeing such big changes in your application after migrating to MDC.

There is nothing you can do about it. The old style is not available anymore for the given reason. You now have to choose between "fill" or "outline", which both are significantly different from the former "standard" appearance.

Comment: Hi @JSON Derulo, can you please tell me how did you refer to what material 15 class  needs to be updated/replaced with which MDC equivalent class? Is there any documentation/website to refer and compare to resolve the TODO(mdc-migration): comments left by MDC migration step? And to fix all the css issues?